# Interpreting the output of a DNN using binary cross entropy as loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a Tensorflow image classification DNN that uses binary crossentropy as its loss and the corresponding label mode binary in the tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory call. When i train the model and run inference on images the predictions outputs are something like [[-3.5601902]] or [[2.1026382]]. How im to interpret that to get to which of the two classes the model is assigning the image. I think the answer would be an implementation of a softmax function but im not getting it right.

Call to tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
images_directory,
label_mode="binary",
validation_split=0.2,
subset="training",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
images_directory,
label_mode="binary",
validation_split=0.2,
subset="validation",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size)
```

and the model

```
model = Sequential([
layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also any input on the model would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit confusing what you are trying to achieve.

If you are doing a binary classification ( which I believe you are ), the size of your output layer should not be 'num_classes', it should be 1 with a sigmod for activation function. if you did that, the output 'p' would be the probability of class 1 and 1-'p' the probability of class 0. It seems that you mixed a bit of multi categorical approach with binary classification.

I guess the only thing possible to say about those values is that they are logit outputs.